# How to extract only specific part from xml files and merge them?

Tags: xml, shell, sed, scripting, grep

I have many xml files which I want to merge into one file. I don't want to merge them from root but from one of the child.
How to proceed with it using grep/sed/awk statements?

XML 1:

```
<root>
   <version>AB</version>
   <Data>
       <Title>MyTitle</Title>
       <SubTitle>Mysub</SubTitle>
   </Data>
   <file author="JXJX" name="MyFile1">
       <desc>File1</desc>
       <field>Random Field</field>
   </file>
<root>
```

XML 2:

```
<root>
   <version>AB</version>
   <Data>
       <Title>MyTitle 2</Title>
       <SubTitle>Mysub 2</SubTitle>
   </Data>
   <file author="HIGH" name="MyFile2">
       <desc>File2</desc>
       <field>Random Field</field>
   </file>
<root>
```

I want the following XML file:

```
<root>
    <file author="JXJX" name="MyFile1">
       <desc>File1</desc>
       <field>Random Field</field>
    </file>
    <file author="HIGH" name="MyFile2">
       <desc>File2</desc>
       <field>Random Field</field>
    </file>
</root>
```

Comment: Hi @Yankee, Welcome on Stack Overflow. Can you provide what you have tried, a minimum reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For files as simple as your examples, you may get away with a short `sed` command which prints the first line, all lines from `<file` to `</file>`, and the last line:

```
sed -n '1p;/<file/,/<\/file>/p;$p' XML1 XML2
```

Comment: Hi @Armali, Thanks for the answer. In case I have an XML tag like <file> .... </file>. This will not work. Can you please tell how to modfiy the statement in such case.

Comment: I just removed the space after `<file`; then it works for tags with as well as without attributes, as long as there's no other tag named `<file…`.

Answer (score 1):

Please [don't parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858), but use a proper parser like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) instead:

```
$ xidel -se '
  element root {
    doc("1.xml")//file,
    doc("2.xml")//file
  }
' --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent
<root>
  <file author="JXJX" name="MyFile1">
    <desc>File1</desc>
    <field>Random Field</field>
  </file>
  <file author="HIGH" name="MyFile2">
    <desc>File2</desc>
    <field>Random Field</field>
  </file>
</root>
```